# problems with `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` in android

Tags: android

According to docs,`getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name")` is the great way to launch any app but I think it has some disadvantage is that it launches the app perfectly but it always create new instance of that launched app or it just start the main activity of the launched app even if the app is running in background with different activity.So my question is how to use `getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name")` to bring the particular app to front if it is already running on our system same as we launch the running app by long pressing home button in our android phone.Is there any solution...